# Remove inner element from JSON array in Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I have the following JSON array.

```
[{
    "Group": "Title1",
    "subGroup": [{
        "name": "Test1",
        "id": 3
    }, {
        "name": "Hello",
        "id": 4
    }]
},
 {
    "Group": "Title2",
    "subGroup": [{
        "name": "Test2",
        "id": 5
    }, {
        "name": "Test2",
        "id": 6
    }]
}]
```

I want to remove the entire JSON object only if name = "Hello". I have the following code

```
  let deleteIndex=-1;
    MyData.forEach(sampleData => {
      deleteIndex = sampleData.subGroup.findIndex(data=> data.name === 'Hello');
      console.log(deleteIndex);
      delete sampleData.subGroup[deleteIndex];
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(MyData));
  }
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. I want data like this

```
 [{
        "Group": "Title1",
        "subGroup": [{
            "name": "Test1",
            "id": 3
        }]
    },
     {
        "Group": "Title2",
        "subGroup": [{
            "name": "Test2",
            "id": 5
        }, {
            "name": "Test2",
            "id": 6
        }]
    }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using filter.

```js
const arr = [{
    "Group": "Title1",
    "subGroup": [{
        "name": "Test1",
        "id": 3
    }, {
        "name": "Hello",
        "id": 4
    }]
},
 {
    "Group": "Title2",
    "subGroup": [{
        "name": "Test2",
        "id": 5
    }, {
        "name": "Test2",
        "id": 6
    }]
}];
for (const item of arr) {
  item.subGroup = item.subGroup.filter(subitem => subitem.name !== 'Hello');
}
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `map` and `filter` for this.

```
const newData = MyData.map(data => ({
   // spread the old data properties
   ...data,
   // for the subGroup array, only keep the ones where .name does not equal 'hello'
   subGroup: data.subGroup.filter(subData => subData.name !== 'hello'),
}));

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const input = [{
    "Group": "Title1",
    "subGroup": [{
        "name": "Test1",
        "id": 3
    }, {
        "name": "Hello",
        "id": 4
    }]
},
 {
    "Group": "Title2",
    "subGroup": [{
        "name": "Test2",
        "id": 5
    }, {
        "name": "Test2",
        "id": 6
    }]
}];

const output = input.map((item) => ({
  Group: item.Group,
  subGroup: item.subGroup.filter(({ name }) => name !== 'Hello')
}));

console.log(output);
```